# Early 1980s made-for-TV-movie where the equation √e^5u^5 is significant

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to remember the name of a terrible made-for-TV-movie from the US from the early 80s. The main thing I remember about the movie is that there was a scientist or mathematician who discovered an equation that had some sort of significance to the plot. The equation was `√e^5u^5`.

In the end, the significance of the equation ends up being that if you look at the math symbols as letters, it spells out "Jesus".

I don't remember much else about the movie other than people repeatedly writing out the above equation or entering it into calculators and not seeing the significance of it. I remember one person entering into a calculator with the multi-segment LEDs that were popular at the time.

This TV movie aired in the US on one of the 3 major networks of the time (ABC, NBC, or CBS). I don't remember any of the particular actors or actresses. If I had to guess, they were probably second-stringers from prime time soap operas of the era.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, I *have not* seen this film, but it sound like it could be it:
[Holocaust 2000](http://www.britishhorrorfilms.co.uk/holocaust2000.shtml)

The reason I think this is because, well, it *sounds super terrible* AND the following:

> As Caine cheerily goes ahead with blowing the crap out of some holy caves, the viewers are treated to documentary footage of real famine victims (tasteful) overlaid with carvings of the word IESUS from the cave walls. This is supposed to be the way they spelled "Jesus" in the olden days - and ever noticed how it looks like the equation "2V231" as seen in a mirror? That's comedy plot "twist" number two...

and

> A computer's dire warning that Satanic things are afoot, with the old "two square root of two three one is Iesus spelt backwards" chestnut ("The name of Jesus written backwards has always been used as the symbol of the antichrist!" warns a friendly Priest destined to buy it in a plane crash).

It seems as though 'equations' figure heavily into the film. The time frame fits (it was 1977 when it was released).

Comment: Wow! Nice find! This is likely it. I'm going to do a bit of research on it to verify and will probably accept this as the answer shortly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep! That's definitely it! Apparently you can watch the full movie here: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Num0jrVVCQM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Num0jrVVCQM).